# Create Graph Bar Using Array Modifier With Taller Bars Infinitely?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode, geometry-nodes

Is it possible to create a graph bar where each proceeding bar is taller and taller?

Can I do this without using any code?

Or what way could I make the next cubes essentially double then triple.... to infinity?

I don't want to manually have to increase the height of each cube because that would take forever

[image]

Comment: If your question was solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted Answer". This will make it easier for others to see which way leads to the solution, and the question will no longer appear as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still didn't get a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 4):

This is a classic task for *geometry nodes*.

In this case, you simply use your cube as geometry in the node `Group Input`, instantiate it along a `Mesh Line` with the node `Instance on Points`, and scale the instances with an accumulated value.

[image]

If you want to increment by a custom value, just switch the node `Accumulate Field` from *Integer* to *Float* and use as *Value* any other value you want to accumulate.

You can of course also scale the other axes of your cube and control the offset via the node `Accumulate Field` as well.

However, instead of accumulating a fixed value, in this example you use the continuous index of points:

[image]

Comment: is it possible to increase the scale of each new bar by a small amount? I only saw it scales everything at once, but not sure how to scale just the proceeding ones to get bigger and bigger

Comment: Yes, of course: Switch the node `Accumulate Field` from *Integer* to *Float* and use as *Value* any other value you want to accumulate.

Comment: so that makes them taller, but I meant like scale so some are thicker and wider as well.

Comment: ...thicker and wider per random or accumulated? ...it would be great if you could provide an image of what you want exactly.

Comment: basically cube 1 is 1x1, cube 2 is 2x2, cube 3 is 3x3, etc or a way to automate the scaling of the next cubes by 50% or X percent